# PredictionIO evaluation in classifier

Tags: prediction, predictionio

Has someone achieved to make an evaluation correctly using PredictionIO?

I am using the classification template in a server, but using more attributes, it is trained with a dataset I got and makes predictions well. However, it fails doing the evaluation, and I have all the data labeled, the data I use to train the algorithm...

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   requirement failed: RDD[labeledPoints] in PreparedData cannot be
>   empty. Please check if DataSource generates TrainingData and
>   Preparator generates PreparedData  correctly.

DataSource.scala and Preparator.scala should work as they are.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Finally I got It starting all the again. For classification, be sure to follow the guide steps and:
1. Add all the attrs you use about your dataset to Engine, Evaluation, DataSource and NaiveBayesAlgorithms scala files.
2. Rename the app name for yours in engine.json and Evaluation.scala.
3. Re build the app "pio build --verbose".
4. Now you can evaluate, "pio eval yourpackagename.AccuracyEvaluation yourpackagename.EngineParamsList"

Comment: Please create an answer and set it as the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got It starting all the again. For classification, be sure to follow the guide steps and: 1. Add all the attrs you use about your dataset to Engine, Evaluation, DataSource and NaiveBayesAlgorithms scala files. 2. Rename the app name for yours in engine.json and Evaluation.scala. 3. Re build the app "pio build --verbose". 4. Now you can evaluate, "pio eval yourpackagename.AccuracyEvaluation yourpackagename.EngineParamsList"

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation (using command shown in the doc), is working with the latest, given that you set spark to 1.4.1 in your build.sbt . See this github issue: 
https://github.com/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-textclassification/issues/2